# How to Filter Only JavaScript Files (.js) with fs.readdirSync After TypeScript Build?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node.js-fs

I'm facing an issue with my Node.js TypeScript project. Despite using tsc to compile TypeScript files into JavaScript, when I utilize fs.readdirSync to list files in a directory, both TypeScript files (.ts) and JavaScript files (.js) are present in the results.

I've verified that my TypeScript configuration (tsconfig.json) and output directory are correctly set up. How can I ensure that fs.readdirSync only returns JavaScript files (.js) while excluding TypeScript files (.ts) from the results after a TypeScript build?

After build my models files are changed to `user.model.js` but `fs.readdirSync` still pulls it as `user.model.ts`

```
const currentDirectory = path.resolve();
const currentFileName = path.basename(__filename);

fs.readdirSync(path.join(currentDirectory, 'src/models'))
    .filter((file) => {
        console.log('file', file);
        // Check for .js or .ts extension with the .model.js or .model.ts pattern and exclude the current file
        return /\.model\.(js|ts)$/.test(file) && file !== currentFileName;
    })
    .forEach((file) => {});
```

```
"build": "rimraf dist && tsc --project tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json"
```

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": ["ES2022"],
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
        "paths": {
            "#src/*": ["./*"],
            "#utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
            "#routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
            "#models/*": ["src/models/*"],
            "#configs/*": ["src/configs/*"],
            "#database/*": ["src/database/*"],
            "#services/*": ["src/services/*"],
            "#constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
            "#interfaces/*": ["src/interfaces/*"],
            "#validators/*": ["src/validators/*"],
            "#controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"],
            "#middlewares/*": ["src/middlewares/*"],
            "#repositories/*": ["src/repositories/*"]
        },
        "plugins": []
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: You're still reading `src/models`, which is your **TypeScript** source.

Comment: yes the problem was in this `'src/models'`. after build it was still trying to access `root/src/model` although it should be `root/dist/models`

i have configure the path based on the environment

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU so did this solve your issue?

Comment: @ghybs yes i have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the issue in the following line: path.join(currentDirectory, 'src/models').

The problem was that it was attempting to access project-root/src/models, but to access the models from the dist directory, the correct path should be project-root/dist/models.

Instead of using path.resolve(), I used __dirname because it represents the current directory in which the file is located.

Here's the modified code:

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file) => {
        // Check for .js or .ts extension with the .model.js or .model.ts pattern and exclude the current file
        return /\.model\.(js|ts)$/.test(file) && file !== currentFileName;
    })
    .forEach((file) => {
        try {
            // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-dynamic-require, @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires, global-require
            const { default: model } = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
            model.initModel(sequelizeInstance);
            models[model.name] = model;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error importing model from file ${file}:`, error);
        }
    });
```